# In-degree and out-degree of two distinct vertices in a directed graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to prove or give a counterexample that for all $n\ge2$ there exists a directed graph of order $n$ such that every pair of distinct vertices have different out-degrees and same in-degrees.

Comment: Well, I don't see how that can hold up for $n = 2$.  Take 2 vertices $u,v$.  If there's no arc between them, they have the same out-degree.  If there's one arc, say $(u,v)$, then the in-degrees are different.  If both arcs $(u,v), (v, u)$ are there, same out-degree.  And even if you allow the same arc multiple times, this argument goes on...

Comment: But then you add a loop from $u$ to $u$...

Comment: Is this supposed to be allowing repeated and loop edges?

Comment: Ah with loops this should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I would prove this by induction. So set your vertices up in a linear fashion. The one endpoint vertex has all outgoing arcs to other vertices, and then self-loops to account for the in-degree. The other end-point vertex has no outgoing arcs. The vertices in the middle each have an appropriate number of self-loops as well as arcs to the each of the next vertices in line.

Note: This assumes that you a directed multigraph is permissible here.